# Are Muslims Noahides?

Tags: islam, noahidism

If a person believes Islam is he righteous gentile and Noahide?
or Are all muslims automatically Noahides because they believe in strict monotheism?

Is there authoritative ruling about this issue?

This question was raised on here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udYM4FuYdiA

very good answer by  Rabbi Tovia Singer but I would like to confirm it with some sources please! He said that Islam has unique status in Judaism and I dont think it is related to another question.

Comment: I can't view the Youtube link, now. But, even without this, all humanity emanated from the children of Noach, as the prior generation was wiped out during the flood. Are you asking if the Muslim religion follows the laws of B'nei Noach?

Comment: Believing in Islam doesn't mean much in Jewish tradition. He would have to act righteously to be a righteous gentile. Perhaps you mean to ask if one acts according to the laws of the bnei Noah *but* believes in Islam if he is considered a righteous gentile.

Comment: In general, it is hard to come by "authorative rulings" on issues without practical significance.

Comment: @Daniel probably not a dupe. This asks about noahidism in general. That asked about a controversial category devised by Rambam on the basis of a non-Talmudic Midrash which includes certain Noahides who accept the 7 mitzvot for certain reasons.

Comment: I think other question is more general!

Comment: The main problem would be that they follow the tenets because Mohammed declared it and not that Hashem gave them to Noach and gave the torah to Moshe. Claiming the cmel driver was a navi (which he obviously was not) may be enough. The other question is indeed a duplicate and is written more generally.

Comment: @LN6595 It has been very relevant to discussions of Heter Mekhira where some wanted to argue that Muslims were similar enough to Gerei Toshav to allow selling them land. That would indicate that they are at least Noahides. That's practical significance.

Comment: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/80174/surah-al-ahqaf-4631-is-mohammed-allah-in-some-way